# A confluence attachment event plugin

Tags: plugins, confluence

I would like to make a plugin with some kind of a listener when an attachment is uploaded / or dragdropped. Anyone who might help?

Comment: have you tried answers.atlassian.com?

Answer (score 1):

There is one specialized Event extending ConfluenceEvent named [AttachmentEvent](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/event/events/content/attachment/AttachmentEvent.html) - I think this is what you should listen to.

In the next step you simply need to implement an event listener module as describe in [Atlassian's developer documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Event+Listener+Module).